# Get a list of all values in a column of a DataTable in the correct type

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable, ado.net

I have a `DataTable` which I populate using a `SqlDataAdapter` like this:

```
Dim dt = New DataTable("Students")
Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT [Id] ,[Name] FROM [Students]", myADO_SqlConnection)
Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter With {.SelectCommand = cmd}
da.Fill(dt)
```

In my database, `Id` is of type `Int`.

I want to get a list of the values in the `Id` column. For this I write:

```
Dim Ids = dt.AsEnumerable.Select(Function(r) r.Item("Id")).ToList
```

The **problem** is, that this gives me a `List(Of Object)`. Is there a way that I directly get a `List(Of Integer)` without casting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `DataRow` extension method [`Field`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.field(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim Ids = dt.AsEnumerable.Select(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)("Id")).ToList()
```

This method also supports nullable types, so if a column can be null you can write:

```
Dim nullableColumnList As List(Of Int32?) = dt.AsEnumerable().
    Select(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32?)("NullableColumnName")).
    ToList()
```